# How to add a class of "active" by checking current function name

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, class, addition

i am trying to add a css class of "active" to the list item by checking which function the user is on i am using codeigniter to build a cms and using class names and functions to navigate through the site

```
    class Main extends CI_Controller {

        public function index(){    
            // Get all Articles
            $data['title'] = 'Latest Articles';
            $data['main_content'] = 'main';
            $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
        }
        public function article($slug) {
            // Get Article details
            $data['article'] = $this->Games_model->get_game_details($slug);
            $data['title'] = $data['article']->title;

            $data['main_content'] = 'article';
            $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
        }
}
```

i'm using this code to create a class of main so that users can visit my site with this url `"localhost/cms/main"` or `"localhost/cms/"`
i want to add a class by checking which function we are on

For example
if we are on `"localhost/cms/"` the i want to add a class to home link
else i want to add a class to article or which ever function i am on

Hope you understood what i want to say here

So any help Folkss ??

Comment: `$data` is an array. You have to specify what element you want to use

Comment: Not that clear, but you could pass your var to the `$data` array, which is sent to your layout.

Comment: a little detail if i may ask ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get name of class in Codeigniter

```
$this->router->fetch_class();
```

To get name of method in Codeigniter

```
$this->router->fetch_method();
```

Comment: Thank you brother .. now i can use these methods i've found here thanks a bundle ..

Comment: if my ans is working fine accept my ans it will help for others also

Comment: well the first ans was accepted but it perhaps the server didn't updated acception.. still your ans helped me but i can not accept two

Comment: Thanks for the instruction though

Answer (score 3):

you can use the uri segment and routes

in routes.php

```
$route['main'] = 'main/index';
$route['article'] = 'main/article';
```

in view

```
<a <?php echo ($this->uri->segment(1)=='main') ? 'class="active"':''; ?> href="<?php echo base_url('main'); ?>">Main</a>
<a <?php echo ($this->uri->segment(1)=='article') ? 'class="active"':''; ?> href="<?php echo base_url('article'); ?>">Articles</a>
```

for more details check the documentation, for routes [click here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) and for uri segment [click here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

Comment: i did a study on those it helped thanks ... :) your answer is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you're already setting the active page in `$data['main_content']`, you should be able to do following in your view (your navigation links, or wherever you want):

```
<a <?php echo $main_content=='main'?' class="active"':''?> href="your_main_url">Main</a>
<a <?php echo $main_content=='article'?' class="active"':''?> href="your_articles_url">Articles</a>
```

This basically checks the `$data['main_content']` variable you've set AND passed to view in your controller, and prints `class="active"` for the active page.

Comment: Yeah thanks bro... i followed this method and it worked

Comment: I'm not your bro, pal! Glad it worked. You should accept an answer if your problem is solved though.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Hearner already commented, you can use the `$data` array to add extra data which you can send to your template. In your case you can also use your `$data['main_content']` item to specify the current page.

Build your template in such a way that the menu is also a separate template, otherwise you need to do the checks for the current active page on every page template.

So to give you an example:

```
// your navigation template file
<ul class="nav">
    <li <?php echo ($main_content === 'main' ? 'class="active"' : '') ?>><a href="..">Main</a></li>
    <li <?php echo ($main_content === 'article' ? 'class="active"' : '') ?>><a href="..">Acticles</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that did solve my problem for today .  :)